# Temporary changing the time of setInterval

Tags: javascript, setinterval

The timing value in `setInterval` determines the next time at which the function is going to be invoked again. For example:

```
t = 8000;    
myFunction(){
   if (someCondition){
        //halt setInterval
        //t = 5000;
       // setInterval(myFunction,t);
   }
    // do some logic
}

setInterval(myFunction, t);
```

The problem is changing of `t` will not affect the time that I want the current call to be remained before the next call. In other words, is there any way to halt `setInterval` and then I can reset it again with new time?

Comment: Use `clearInterval` to cancel the old timer and then use `setInterval` to start a new one.

Comment: You call clearInterval on the timerid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do something like that, you're better off doing your own interval control with `setTimeout`.

```
var shortInterval = 2000, longInterval = 4000;

function timerCode() {
  // do something
  if (whatever) {
    setTimeout(timerCode, shortInterval);
  }
  else {
    setTimeout(timerCode, longInterval);
  }
}

setTimeout(timerCode, longInterval);
```

That way, on each iteration of the timer you can decide how long it should be until the next iteration. If you want to stop, just don't reset the timer at all.

Comment: Why doing my own interval is better?

Comment: @sємsєм because it's much more flexible. There's no real performance issue, and it's not significantly more code. A lot of people in fact recommend never using `setInterval`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use clearInterval().

```
    var myInterval = setInterval(myFunction, t);

    ...

    clearInterval(myInterval);

...

myInterval = setInterval(myFunction, 1000);
```