# Dynamically change the setInterval value as its running

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout, setinterval

I've seen a number of examples but none of them do exactly what I need. This seems the closest but uses setTimeout and is not quite what I'm needing to do. [Change setInterval value dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30725455/change-setinterval-value-dynamically)

I have a dropdown/select that gives the user a choice of refresh times, 5 seconds, 10 seconds and up to 60 seconds as well as stop the refresh all together.

```
<select id="refTime" name="refTime" size="7" onchange="chngAutoRef();">
                <option value="60">Time to refresh      </option>
                <option value="0"> No Auto Refresh      </option>
                <option value="5"> 5 seconds            </option>
                <option value="10"> 10 seconds          </option>
                <option value="20"> 20 seconds          </option>
                <option value="30"> 30 seconds          </option>
                <option value="60"> 60 (default)        </option>

</select>
```

And I'm using the javascript.

```
var interval = 60;

function chngAutoRef() {
    clearInterval(autoRefId);
    var autoRefId = null;

    var interval = $('#refTime').find(":selected").val();
    var newButton = "every " + interval;
    $("#refbutton").attr('value',newButton);  // rename the ref button

    if (typeof interval == 'undefined' ) {interval = 60;}

    if (autoRefId !== null) {
        $("#autoref").html('Start Auto Ref'); // You see this if Refresh is not automatically happening
            clearInterval(autoRefId);
                autoRefId = null;
    } else {
        interval = interval * 1000;
        $("#autoref").html('Stop Auto Ref'); // You see this if Refresh is automatically happening
            autoRefId = setInterval(function() {
                showActivities(document.getElementById("select1").value);}, interval);
    }
} // end of function chngAutoRef()

chngAutoRef();
```

When the page launches the default is 60 seconds, if the user then selects 5 seconds it refreshes every 5 seconds. But if the user then changes the selection to 10 seconds (or any other) the refresh become erratic and updates a 5 or 10 or 1 second (anything but the 10 requested).

I've tried using setTimeout() instead but I don't understand how to make it do what I need.

Comment: You are not clearing the intervals so it appears erratic but its really just stacking all the uncleared intervals on top of one another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your original code you were not clearing any of the setInterval calls you initialized because the variable `autoRefId` was undefined when you were passing it into `clearInterval`. As a result if you clicked on the button multiple times the browser would layer all of the interval functions on top of one another making appear "erratic".

Like @Fenton mentioned, this is how you should approach the issue. I made minor adjustments to other areas of your code as well.

```js
var interval = 60;

var autoRefId = null;
function chngAutoRef() {
    clearInterval(autoRefId);
    var interval = $('#refTime').find(":selected").val();
    var newButton = "every " + interval;
    $("#refbutton").attr('value',newButton);  // rename the ref button

    if (typeof interval == 'undefined' ) {interval = 60;}

    //not sure what this was doing..autoRefId would have always been null here.
    //you also don't need to null autoRefId in this function.
    /*if (autoRefId !== null) {
        $("#autoref").html('Start Auto Ref'); // You see this if Refresh is not automatically happening
            clearInterval(autoRefId);
                autoRefId = null;
    } else {*/
        interval = interval * 1000;
        $("#autoref").html('Stop Auto Ref'); // You see this if Refresh is automatically happening
            autoRefId = setInterval(function() {
                showActivities(document.getElementById("select1").value);}, interval);
    //}
} // end of function chngAutoRef()

//chngAutoRef();
//"*" means we are looking for the click event across the entire doc.
$("*").click(function(){showActivities(document.getElementById("select1").value);});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="refTime" name="refTime" size="7" onchange="chngAutoRef();">
                <option value="60">Time to refresh      </option>
                <option value="0"> No Auto Refresh      </option>
                <option value="5"> 5 seconds            </option>
                <option value="10"> 10 seconds          </option>
                <option value="20"> 20 seconds          </option>
                <option value="30"> 30 seconds          </option>
                <option value="60"> 60 (default)        </option>

</select>
```

Comment: All of the responses were correct. I did leave the var definition inside the function (dumb mistake). I corrected that and simplified the code as Lucas suggested. It seems to work great now.

Comment: How do I get it to honor a left click now? The left click should do a refresh any time its clicked.

Comment: @Keith D Kaiser  just use jquery `click()` function and pass `chngAutoRef` as the handler. If you want the event listener to fire on every click then bind the event handler to the entire document. Here is some docs: https://api.jquery.com/click/

Comment: Does this look correct?   $("#refbutton").click(function() {
 $("chngAutoRef").click();
});

Comment: @KeithDKaiser Actually this is what you want I think..(edited again after more thought)

Answer (score 1):

Your handle is currently scoped to the function (i.e. each time you call it you create a new `autoRefId`).

Move that variable declaration out of the function for it to be the same instance across multiple calls...

```
// Moved out of the function...
var autoRefId = null;

function chngAutoRef() {
    //...
```

Now when you clear the timeout using `autoRefId` it will refer to the global variable (of which there is one), rather than the local one (of which there is one per function call).

Remember to remove the `var autoRefId = null;` line from within the function so you don't have a name clash.

Answer (score 1):

The task is to start, pause or resume an interval timer that calls

```
function() {showActivities(document.getElementById("select1").value);}, interval);
```

at a variable interval.

Firstly, for a post on SO, use a dummy function to allow readers to reproduce the error. The posted HTML code is also missing `#refbutton` and `#autoref` elements, which makes it harder to get help.

My testing suggested `#refbutton` is a text input element rather than a button. Did you intend to allow users to modify the input with their own refresh interval time? If so that must be part of the design.

The refresh timer appears to have multiple potential sources of interval: the current interval in use, the selected interval, the interval in use before pausing refresh with a refresh time of zero, and the interval contained in a `#refbutton` element value.

The code contains no code to sort this out. I managed a fair amount but fell short of restarting the timer with the previous timer value, after stopping it in the select box, or restarting after changing the value of `#refbutton`.

As others have pointed out, existing timer calls must be stopped using a timerId value held outside the change interval function. Also `var interval` in the function shadows the `interval` definition in outer scope. However, fixing technical coding errors does not address lack of design. I suggest re-assesment of the code architecture, and possible refactoring of function interaction, to best meet design aims. Keeping stopping the timer by selecting or entering a timer value of zero is possible, *but it complicates the algorithm a lot.*